# Need Help about how to use Google Maps API

Tags: android

Some one had about document , curriculum about Google Maps API  could share me because i prepare do de project about Google Maps API for my last exam . I know i can find guide about google maps api on developer.android.com but i dont understand

Some one had document , curriculum about Google Maps API  could share me please

Comment: I think googles tutorial covers everything you need to know for a simple project: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

Answer (score 0):

Following links may be helpful to you:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html

http://www.guidingtech.com/11106/use-offline-google-maps-android/

Answer (score 0):

First find out your debug.keystore in your system

you will find it here

```
Windows Vista: C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
OS X and Linux: ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

then

fire this command in command line

```
$ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android
```

you will get md5 key as output

you need to click on this

```
https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup
```

follow this steps

```
If you don't have a Google account, use the link on the page to set one up.
Read the Android Maps API Terms of Service carefully. If you agree to the terms, indicate so using the checkbox on the screen.
Paste the MD5 certificate fingerprint of the certificate that you are registering into the appropriate form field.
Click "Generate API Key"
```

add your generated key into your code

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:enabled="true"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:apiKey="example_Maps_ApiKey_String"
 />
```

add this as well

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.package.name">
 ...
 <application android:name="MyApplication" >
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
 ...
 </application>
```

that's it

Comment: I did show the map view but i can't code  an advance function example : find the service , hotel , restaurant , ATM , bus in radius .but I dont know where i can begin . May be  my knowledge not enough So stupid >_<

Comment: I think you should use Foursquare API for find services and show it on google map like i have used FS api to find restaurant  public static final String FOURSQUARE_VENUE_URL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?"
   + "ll=(lat,lon)&client_id=(app client id)&client_secret=(appclientsecret)&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&limit=30&intent=browse&radius=1500&v=(currentdate)";

Comment: Even you should use overlay to show the resturants, etc on google map. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview here is the example